# Task.WaitAll and Exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I have a problem with exception handling and parallel tasks.

The code shown below starts 2 tasks and waits for them to finish. My problem is, that in case a task throws an exception, the catch handler is never reached.

```
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        try
        {                
            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(TaskMethod1));
            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(TaskMethod2));

            var arr = tasks.ToArray();                
            Task.WaitAll(arr);
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            // do something
        }
```

However when I use the following code to wait for the tasks with a timeout, the exception is caught.

```
 while(!Task.WaitAll(arr,100));
```

I seem to be missing something, as the documentation for `WaitAll` describes my first attempt to be the correct one. Please help me in understanding why it is not working.

Comment: What do TaskMethod1 and TaskMethod2 do? What thread are you executing on? If you could turn this into a short but *complete* example (like my answer) that would really help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Can't reproduce this - it works fine for me:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
        Task t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            throw new Exception("Oops");
        });

        try
        {
            Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
            Console.WriteLine("All done");
        }
        catch (AggregateException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

That prints "Something went wrong" just as I'd expect.

Is it possible that one of your tasks isn't finished? `WaitAll` really does wait for all the tasks to complete, even if some have already failed.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer Jon! My problem was/is that the other task depends on the failed task, therefore it would wait forever on the failed task. My idea was, that the exception is caught immediately when a task fails, which is not the case. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @pivotnig - take a look at 'Creating Task Continuations' here to express the dependency explicitly -  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

Comment: @thumbmunkeys didn't realize this posted this. It's exactly what I asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47820918/695964

Answer (score 12):

Here's how I solved the problem, as alluded to in the comments on my answer/question (above):

The caller catches any exceptions raised by the tasks being coordinated by the barrier, and signals the other tasks with a forced cancellation:

```
CancellationTokenSource cancelSignal = new CancellationTokenSource();
try
{
    // do work
    List<Task> workerTasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (Worker w in someArray)
    {
        workerTasks.Add(w.DoAsyncWork(cancelSignal.Token);
    }
    while (!Task.WaitAll(workerTasks.ToArray(), 100, cancelSignal.Token)) ;

 }
 catch (Exception)
 {
     cancelSignal.Cancel();
     throw;
 }
```

Comment: This is nice. Never realised this use case for `CancellationTokenSource`.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to create a call for each item in a collection, which turned out something like this:

```
var parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
  foreach (var acct in AccountList)
    {
      var currAcctNo = acct.Number;
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
        MyLocalList.AddRange(ProcessThisAccount(currAcctNo));
      }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
      Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
  });
```

I had to add the Thread.Sleep after each addition of a child task because if I didn't, the process would tend to overwrite the currAcctNo with the next iteration.  I would have 3 or 4 distinct account numbers in my list, and when it processed each, the ProcessThisAccount call would show the last account number for all calls.  Once I put the Sleep in, the process works great.

Comment: that might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009181/parallel-foreach-vs-task-factory-startnew

Comment: Parallel.ForEach more efficient ?

Comment: what does this answer have to do with the original question? no exceptions here