# What does await do in this function?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I thought I understand the `async-await` pattern in `C#` but today I've found out I really do not.

In a simple code snippet like this. I have `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;` defined already.

```
public static async Task Test()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string str;
    for (int i = 1000; i <= 1100; i++)
        str = await client.GetStringAsync($"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{i1}");
}
```

What does `await` do here? Initially I thought since this is in async-await pattern, it means basically HttpClient will initiate all HTTP GET calls in a multi-threaded fashion, i.e. basically all the Urls should be fetched at once.

But when I'm using Fiddler to analyze the behavior I've found it really fetches the URLs sequentially.

I need to change it to this to make it work:

```
public static async Task<int> Test()
{
    int ret = 0;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 1000; i <= 1100; i++)
    {
        var i1 = i;
        var task = Task.Run(() => client.GetStringAsync($"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{i1}"));
        taskList.Add(task);
    }
    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
    return ret;
}
```

This time the URLs are fetched in parallel. So what does the `await` keyword really do in the first code snippet?

Comment: Things in a loop happen one after the other, not in parallel. That is true whether or not the loop contains an await.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It ***awaits*** the completion of the HTTP request. The code resumes (`for` iteration...) only after every single request is complete.

Your 2nd version works precisely because it **doesn't await** for each task to complete before initiating the following tasks, and only waits for all the tasks to complete after all have been started.

What async-await is useful for is allowing the *calling* function to continue doing other things while the asynchronous function is awaiting, as opposed to synchronous ("normal") functions that block the calling function until completion.

Comment: Thanks Amit. That's the place where I've got a confusion.

Comment: one thing to note : if there was a line of code after your loop. That would be executed straight away in your first solution. In your second solution if there was a line after Task.WaitAll(), it would have to wait for all the HTTP requests to finish first and then executed.

Answer (score 13):

An `await` is an *asynchronous wait*. It is not a blocking call and allows the caller of your method to continue. The remainder of the code inside the method after an `await` will be executed when the `Task` returned has completed.

In the first version of your code, you allow callers to continue. However, each iteration of the loop will wait until the `Task` returned by `GetStringAsync` has completed. This has the effect of *sequentially* downloading each URL, rather than *concurrently*.

Note that the second version of your code is *not asynchronous* insofar as it uses threads to perform the work in **parallel**.

If it were asynchronous, it would retrieve the webpage content using only one thread but still **concurrently**.

Something like this (untested):

```
public static async Task<int> Test()
{
    int ret = 0;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 1000; i <= 1100; i++)
    {
        var i1 = i;
        taskList.Add(client.GetStringAsync($"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{i1}"));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray());
    return ret;
}
```

Here, we start the tasks asynchronously and add them to the `taskList`. These tasks are non-blocking and will complete when the download has finished and the string retrieved. Pay attention to the call to `Task.WhenAll` rather than `Task.WaitAll`: the former is asynchronous and non-blocking, the latter is synchronous and blocking. This means that, at the `await`, the caller of this `Test()` method will receive the `Task<int>` returned: but the task will be incomplete until all of the strings are downloaded.

This is what forces `async`/`await` to proliferate throughout the stack. Once the very bottom call is asynchronous, it only makes sense if the rest of the callers all the way up are also asynchronous. Otherwise, you are forced to create a thread via `Task.Run()` calls or somesuch.

Comment: This is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Per the msdn [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx)

> The await operator is applied to a task in an asynchronous method to suspend the execution of the method until the awaited task completes. The task represents ongoing work.

That means the await operator blocks the execution of the for loop until it get a responds from the server, making it sequential.

What you can do is create all the task (so that it begins execution) and then await all of them.

Here's an example from another StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383910/paralell-foreach-with-httpclient-and-continuewith)

```
public IEnumerable<TContent> DownloadContentFromUrls<TContent>(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<TContent>();

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        Task.WaitAll(urls.Select(url =>
        {
            return client.GetAsync(url).ContinueWith(response =>
            {
                var content = JsonConvert.
                    DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<TContent>>(
                        response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

                foreach (var c in content)
                    queue.Enqueue(c);
            });
        }).ToArray());
    }

    return queue;
}
```

There's also good [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh696703.aspx) in msdn that explains how to make parallel request with await.

Edit:

As @GaryMcLeanHall pointed out in a comment, you can change `Task.WaitAll` to `await Task.WhenAll` and add the `async` modifier to make the method return asynchronously

Here's another msdn [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556530.aspx) that picks the example in the first one and adds the use of `WhenAll`.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the method in the example isn't asynchronous: `Task.WaitAll` is a blocking operation. You can `await Task.WhenAll` and mark the `DownloadContentFromUrls` as `async`. Clients are then not blocked.

Comment: Thanks @GaryMcLeanHall for pointing that out, going to edit the answer to add it.

Comment: You _should_ use Task.WhenAll. See https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html. Also, note that the use of `.Result` means that this will throw an `AggregateException` if anything goes wrong, which may not be what you want.