# Generating PDF in Asp.net MVC Application

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5, pdf-generation

I have multiple rows in my SQL database table in which some column I am using for generating the bill, What I am doing is I am fetching all the rows in the list and loop through that list and for each loop row I am performing the calculation and saving it into the list and then saving that into the database.

Now my Question is .
1. Is there any other way to execute the task I mean a better way and
2. How can I insert multiple rows from my Asp.net MVC application into the database(Just need Idea ).
3. And in the end of above process I want to generate a PDF containing all bill information

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using .NET 4.0 and above, you can user  `Parallel.ForEach`. It uses all cores of the machine to finish the task. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009181/parallel-foreach-vs-task-factory-startnew) link.
2. If you are using SQL Server 2008 and above, you can use Table-Valued parameter to pass multiple rows. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code) answer for more detail

Answer (score 0):

.3. To generate PDF you can use [Free Spire.PDF for .NET](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-pdf-component.html#.U_cZfGMfKJs)