# Multi Thread Processing with Parallel.Foreach c# .net4.5.1

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, parallel-processing, .net-4.5

I have an `IEnumerable<customClass>` object that has roughly 10-15 entries, so not a lot, but I'm running into a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` when I try and do

`Parallel.Foreach(..some linq query.., object => { ...stuff....});`

with the enumerable. Here is the code I have that sometimes works, other times doesn't:

```
        IEnumerable<UserIdentifier> userIds = script.Entries.Select(x => x.UserIdentifier).Distinct();

        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(userIds, async userId =>
            {
                Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
                watch.Start();

                _Log.InfoFormat("user identifier: {0}", userId);
                await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    foreach (ScriptEntry se in script.Entries.Where(x => x.UserIdentifier.Equals(userId)))
                    {
                        //    // Run the script //
                        _Log.InfoFormat("waiting {0}", se.Delay);
                        Task.Delay(se.Delay);
                        _Log.InfoFormat("running SelectionInformation{0}", se.SelectionInformation);

                        ExecuteSingleEntry(se);
                        _Log.InfoFormat("[====== SelectionInformation {1} ELAPSED TIME: {0} ======]", watch.Elapsed,
                            se.SelectionInformation.Verb);
                    }

                });

                watch.Stop();
                _Log.InfoFormat("[====== TOTAL ELAPSED TIME: {0} ======]", watch.Elapsed);
            });
        });
```

When the function `ExecuteSingleEntry` is ran, there is a function a few calls deep within that function that creates a temp directory and files. It seems to me, that when I run the `parallel.foreach` the function is getting slammed at once by numerous calls (I'm testing 5 at once currently but need to handle about 10) and isn't creating some of the files I need. But if I hit a break point in the file creation function and just `F5` every time it gets hit I don't have any problems with a file not found exception being thrown.

So, my question is, **how can I achieve running a subset of my `scripts.Entries` in parallel based on the user id within the script entries with a delay of 1 second between each different user id entries being started**?

and a script entry is like:

`UserIdentifier: 141, SelectionInformation: class of stuff, Ids: list of EntryIds, Names: list of Entry Names`

And each user identifier can appear 1 or more times in the array. I want to start all the different user identifiers, more or less, at once. Then `Task` out the different SelectionInformation's tied to a script entry.

`scripts.Entries` is an array of `ScriptEntry`, which is as follows:

```
    [DataMember]
    public TimeSpan Delay { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public SelectionInformation Selection { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public long[] Ids { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Names { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public long UserIdentifier { get; set; }
```

I referenced: [Parallel.ForEach vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009181/parallel-foreach-vs-task-factory-startnew) to obtain the

`Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.Foreach({ }) )` so my UI doesn't lock up on me

Comment: why don't you try making `ExecuteSingleEntry(se);` thread safe

Comment: If all you do in the `Parallel.ForEach` loop is creating some files and directories then you can do it sequentially just as well. The speed may be even higher then. The mass storage performance not the CPU is your bottleneck.

Comment: Depending on what `ExecuteSingleEntry` actually does, you can try putting the file creation and deletion logic in a [lock statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)

Comment: The `ExecuteSingleEntry` does a lot more than create files and directories. It goes out to an oracle database and runs reports against the database. `.wsc` files are created and dumped into directories to analysis on the returned data. I'm attempting to lock the file creation at the moment.

Comment: The parallel.foreach is intended to reproduce 3-5 users per machine running analysis, at once, on a (semi)large collection of data and the execute single entry function chooses the analysis path based on the selection information.

Comment: @B-M if you're trying to simulate multiple users at once, then you need to focus on making `ExecuteSingleEntry(se);` thread safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few principles to apply:

1. [Prefer `Task.Run` over `Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). I describe on my blog why `StartNew` is dangerous; `Run` is a much safer, more modern alternative.
2. Don't pass an `async` lambda to `Parallel.ForEach`. It doesn't make sense, and it won't work right.
3. `Task.Delay` doesn't do anything by itself. You either have to `await` it or use the synchronous version (`Thread.Sleep`).

(In fact, in your case, the internal `StartNew` is meaningless; it's already parallel, and the code - running on a thread pool thread - is trying to start a new operation on a thread pool thread and immediately asynchronously await it???)

After applying these principles:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
  Parallel.ForEach(userIds, userId =>
  {
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    _Log.InfoFormat("user identifier: {0}", userId);
    foreach (ScriptEntry se in script.Entries.Where(x => x.UserIdentifier.Equals(userId)))
    {
      //    // Run the script //
      _Log.InfoFormat("waiting {0}", se.Delay);
      Thread.Sleep(se.Delay);
      _Log.InfoFormat("running SelectionInformation{0}", se.SelectionInformation);

      ExecuteSingleEntry(se);
      _Log.InfoFormat("[====== SelectionInformation {1} ELAPSED TIME: {0} ======]", watch.Elapsed,
          se.SelectionInformation.Verb);
    }

    watch.Stop();
    _Log.InfoFormat("[====== TOTAL ELAPSED TIME: {0} ======]", watch.Elapsed);
  });
});
```