# Task.WaitAll hang when one task throws and another syncs with the first task

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, async-await, task-parallel-library

What should be expected from `Task.WaitAll(t1, t2)`, when `t2`'s execution syncs with `t1`, but `t1` throws an exception before the point it syncs to `t2`? In this case, it's obvious that `t2` will never finish. However **since `t1` throws an exception, I expected `Task.WaitAll(t1,t2)` to return with aggregated exception indicating one of the task fails.**

However this is not the case. It turns out that `Task.WaitAll` hangs waiting forever.

I can argue for this behavior that `Task.WaitAll` does what it claims to wait for ALL tasks to come back, EVEN if one of them already threw an exception. Although I don't prefer it, it is still fine to me as long as I'm aware of it.

However, my question is, is there an alternative API to `Task.WaitAll`, with the behavior of **"waiting for all task to finish, unless one of the task threw an exception"**? I imagine this is the behavior I would need most of the time.

#### Edit 1

I originally used `TaskCompletionSource<>` for the synchronization. But that's immaterial to the point I want to make. So I changed it with a rudimentary polling.

#### Edit 2

I wrote an F# equivalent program (see below) and found that it actually does have the behavior as I expected. As mentioned above, `Task.WhenAll` or `Task.WaitAll` waits for *all* tasks to complete, even if a subset of them failed. However, `Async.Parallel`, as the equivalent of `WhenAll` in F#, fails eagerly when any sub-task fails, as described by [the document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.parallel%5B't%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D) and tested in the program below:

> If all child computations succeed, an array of results is passed to the success continuation. **If any child computation raises an exception, then the overall computation will trigger an exception, and cancel the others.** The overall computation will respond to cancellation while executing the child computations. If cancelled, the computation will cancel any remaining child computations but will still wait for the other child computations to complete.

Is there a C# equivalence to F#'s `Async.Parallel`, in that when waiting for all task to finish, it bails and throws whenever a sub-task fails?

Example that I used:

```
public void Test()
{
    bool t1done = false;

    Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        DoThing(); // throw here
        t1done = true;
    });

    Task t2 = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // polling if t1 is done.
        // or equivelantly: SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => t1done);
        while (!t1done) await Task.Delay(10);
    });

    // t2 will never finish, but t1 threw. So I expect Task.WaitAll to throw rather than blindly wait
    // for t2 EVEN THOUGH t1 threw already.
    Task.WaitAll(t1, t2); // never returns
    // or this could be an async wait, but still this function would never return:
    // await Task.WhenAll(t1,t2);

    Console.WriteLine("done");
}

void DoThing()
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("error");
}
```

**F# "Equivalence" which does have the behavior that I expected**:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let mutable ready : bool = false
    let task1 = async {
        failwith "foo"
        ready <- true
    }

    let task2 = async {
        while not ready do do! Async.Sleep 100
    }

    [| task1; task2 |] 
    |> Async.Parallel // Equivelant to Task.WhenAll() - combining task1 and task1 into a single Async, 
                      // but it throws instead of waiting infinately.
    |> Async.RunSynchronously // run task
    |> ignore

    0
```

Comment: t2 waits not on t1 in your example by the way, but on a third task. If it really waited on t1 - I expect them both to complete with exception.

Comment: @Evk thanks I will clarify in the subject.

Comment: Maybe what you actually want is `Task.WaitAny` or that and a check to see if one errored before waiting on the other one.

Comment: @juharr that doesn't seem to work if you have many of them. You might do a loop `while (Task.WaitAny(...)) ...` but that's essentially a re-implementation of `Task.WatiAll` with my desired behavior. My question is if there's a built in API for that already.

Comment: There is none as far as I know, so loop with WaitAny is the way to go.

Comment: would `t1done.SetException()` work for you?

Comment: I don‘t understand why you expect `WaitAll` to throw rather than waiting. Task completion can be success, failure or cancellation. t2 is not completed. That it can *never* complete is irrelevant. You *specifically* said that you want to wait for all tasks. And that‘s what it‘s doing. The problem in your code is that in the first task you throw the exception and keep the task completion source dangling instead of setting it to error and make the await in the second task throw, too. You could also cancel t1done, but you‘re not doing that either.

Comment: There is also an overload that takes a timeout parameter - > https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235688(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If `t2` can only complete after `t1` has completed, why are you waiting on `t1` at all? Why didn't `t2` throw an exception as well? When you say "sync with", how are you doing that? It's a good idea to try to use the task system for everything, which might mean splitting up your mean a bit more, so that other tasks wait on tasks, and not on synchronization objects.

Comment: @Sefe - thanks for pointing out the right use of task completion source. But I think my point is not specific to that use. My point is with any form of synchronization - even `t2` polling on a variable that would set by `t1`, `Task.WaitAll` would hang. I get it now that `WaitAll` **really** means to wait all. But I personally feel it's a bit counterintuitive and unsafe in such cases.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen That's a good point. I think there's still place for waiting for both tasks. Imagine that `t1` and `t2` are doing things in accordance - e.g., both have 3 steps. t2 step 1 depends on t1 step 1, t1 step2 depends on t2 step1, ... But then the final steps of either task can finish first. In this case it'd still make sense to wait all not any.

Comment: In your example, TaskCompletionSource is completely unnecessary and even implemented incorrectly. t2 can just wait on t1 itself. If you provide more real example - we might suggest a better way to do what you need (noticed you changed example but it's not any better).

Comment: @Evk it's hard for me to provide a more real example - it's a test case I'm writing that set up to parallel tasks which I force them to do things in a specific order trying to prove my code works in a near-race-condition (hence that synchronization parts). Then at the end I `WaitAll` on them. I found this issue because one of the tasks throws and the test case hang.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent API that I am aware of.

I would suggest that you ensure Task t2 can finish! WaitAll() will then throw the exception from t1 as you expect, and it gives you more control over what happens to Task t2.

Assuming your t2 task does a whole heap of other work before it begins polling t1 for completion to benefit from the two tasks running in parallel. How do you know how much of that work it has completed before t1 throws the exception?

WaitAll does not care how the tasks complete, (Cancelled, Faulted or RanToCompletion) only that it is one of those.

There is really no need for the variable t1done, when you can be checking the result of the Task itself:

```
Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    throw null;       
});

Task t2 = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    // check whether task 1 is finished yet 
    while (!t1.IsCompleted) await Task.Delay(10);
    if (t1.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
    {
        // we know that t1 finished successfully and did not throw any 
        // error.           
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We know that t1 did not run to completion");
    }
});

try
{
    Task.WaitAll(t1, t2); 
    // this will now throw the exception from t1 because t2 can also finish
}
catch (AggregateException)
{

}

// For interest sake, you can now view the status of each task.            
Console.WriteLine(t1.Status);
Console.WriteLine(t2.Status);
Console.WriteLine("Finished");
```

Now whether this is the best design for your solution or not I cannot say. Have you looked into Task Continuations? Because if t2 does nothing other than wait for t1 to complete, there are better options... but this should answer the question you have asked directly.

Answer (score -1):

> since `t1` throws an exception, I expected `Task.WaitAll(t1, t2)` to return with aggregated exception indicating one of the task fails

Why do you expect that? `WaitAll` means to wait, emmm, **all** of your tasks, which obviously not the case.

Your code contains inconsistency: you're not failing (or cancelling) the task completion source, which you should do:

```
var ex = new InvalidOperationException("error");
if (shouldThrow)
{
    // SetCanceled 
    // t1done.SetCanceled();

    // or SetException
    // t1done.SetException(ex);

    throw ex;
}
t1done.SetResult(true);
```

> is there an alternative API to `Task.WaitAll`, with the behavior of "waiting for all task to finish, unless one of the task threw an exception"?

You can do a loop with `WaitAny` method so you can check the status of all the tasks completed and throw if any exceptions occur.

PS: consider to switch to `async` methods `WhenAll` and `WhenAny`, and free current thread for additional work. Right now the `Wait*` method will block your thread without doing anything. Also, you should use a cancellation token to be able to cancel all your tasks if one of them fails.

**Edit**:

If we are talking only about the **unhandled** exceptions, then use [`TaskScheduler.UnObservedTaskException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library#unobservedtaskexception-event) event so you can cancel all other tasks being run.

Comment: The exception could be thrown deep in the stack by some other code. Basically you're asking to **explicitly handle** the exception in the task before setting the result on the task completion source. While it definitely avoid the problem, it doesn't seem succinct to the async/await style, where exceptions are naturally flowed. Also the code snippet I gave is an example illustrating the problem. It makes effectively no difference when using `WhenAll` instead.

Comment: No, there is a difference - you have one more thread to do other work. As I already said, you should do a loop with `WhenAny` methods, and cancellation token to notify other tasks that they should cancel the execution.

Comment: @KFL also you can setup a continuation for each task, in that continuation you use the token to cancel all other tasks in case of any exception

Comment: thanks that's for sure another way to avoid the problem. But to me that feels unnecessary plumbing or handling that should be done by the API. I've always compared async/await to how it could draw an analogy to synchronous calls. In synchronous calls, an exception cancels all the subsequent operations. That's why I'm surprised how much plumbing we still have to do with async/await to get things right.

Comment: I still don't understand why do you think that `WaitAll` should throw at first exception. What if other task also throws, how one can handle that? The problem you're describing can be easily solved with tokens, which is natural and easy code to write.

Comment: Right - that's the contract established by `Task.WaitAll` - when exceptions happen in tasks, **aggregate** them into `AggregatedException` - that justifies the behavior of `WaitAll` and I get that. But on the other side - my thought is - what is the point of waiting for unfinished tasks when one of the task threw an **unhandled** exception? The implication of an unhandled exception is that the task failed something that can't be handled. So the waiter eventually will throw too - the difference being wait for all, or throw as soon as one throws...

Comment: Hmm, this is what I missed in your question. If we are talking only about the **unhandled** exceptions, then use [`TaskScheduler.UnObservedTaskException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception) event so you can cancel all other tasks being run.